# Images retaining full size in Firefox/IE but work perfectly in webkit based browsers

Tags: html, css, web

I cannot for the life of me work out this issue with the images for my website.

I've tried using `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` on the `img` element to no avail and I cannot wrap my head around the issue.

The images seem to retain their full 500x250 size in Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer 10 but work and format correctly on Google Chrome and Apple Safari.

I have inputted the HTML and CSS into a JSFiddle and the image persists, the JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W5Edb/) and contains all the required code for the section in question.

The responsive functionality was removed to reduce the size of the code so it won't fold into a single column.

Some help would be appreciated before I have a mental breakdown, thanks.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what the actual issue/question is here.  I don't even see `border-box` anywhere in your fiddle.

Comment: I removed the border-box formatting because I couldn't get it to work.

I read an article on the difference between using webkit and Mozilla and it came up multiple times so I decided to give it a try, it unfortunately didn't remedy the situation.

Image can be found here: http://i.imgur.com/o20gezr.png

The Chrome image is resizing itself whereas the Firefox image is retaining the full size which it shouldn't, it should be scaling down as in the Chrome example.

Metrics are showing the true size of the images in the gallery here:
http://imgur.com/a/BaRvm

Hope that clears things up a little!

Comment: what is it that you are trying to accomplish

Comment: As in my last post, I'd like the images to correctly format as in Chrome.

In Chrome they are formatted properly whereas in Firefox the images don't resize and it causes it all to overlap.
(As seen here: http://imgur.com/a/BaRvm)

I'm unsure where I'm going wrong with it all in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your divs has no width (.alignLeft and .alignRight)

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/W5Edb/1/

```
    .alignLeft {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .alignRight {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

you have to adjust your margin or reduce the % on the divs, but you get the idea and should be able to lay it out the way you need

Comment: They are both contained within a div with the `half` class which width is limited here:

    .half {
         width:49.8%;
     }

Shouldn't this be sufficient?

Comment: I think your problem here answers that questions, inconsistency in different browsers

Comment: I've assigned a specific width to `.alignLeft` and `.alignRight` which seems to have cleared it up.

Not sure why Firefox doesn't like it without a specified width!

Thanks a lot, I would have been at that all day!